# Datatype to store large text values in stored procedures in sybase

Tags: sql, sap-ase, sqldatatypes

Is there a datatype to pass as an out parameter to a stored procedure in Sybase that can hold indefinite amount of data? I learnt that we cannot use text as a datatype. Please help me out

Comment: Refer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071829/i-need-sybase-datatype-to-save-string-of-indefinite-length), that might help

Comment: Thanks Nadeem for your response. But I need an output parameter that I can make use of in a shell script that calls this procedure. So exactly this is not what I was looking for. However, I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need more storage, you may have to logically split your input into 1 or more `varchar(n)`.

The max size for a single `varchar` is the server page size (2k, 4k, 8k, or 16k depending on your environment).

Comment: Thanks Michael. But is there a datatype that can do exactly that?

Comment: No, there is now datatype to automatically do that, that can be used in a stored procedure.